# How to find a DB9-type connector color code?

Tags: connector, wiring

I'm looking to splice wires from a DB-sub (9 pin) connector out to a breadboard but I'm getting different pictures for color-coding which makes me confused. What's more confusing is the connect I have only has 4 wires form the cable despite having 9 pins. The colors (red, black, brown, and orange) include some colors not listed in the color code I found below. I must be looking at the wrong color code but I don't know where to find the right one? Thanks

---

[image: DB9 Color Code].

Comment: why do you feel that all 9 pins should be used?

Comment: Many DB9 have only 3 pins wired: TXD, RXD and Ground. No idea why four, though.

Comment: Thx for the insight. I guess I’ll have to play around with what wires and connections end up working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard for color codes. The chart you found seems to be using the resistor color codes, but shifted by 1 for some reason.

You're just going to have to "buzz out" the connections one-by-one using an ohmmeter or something.